# Three.js on website not appearing on GitHub pages, but working fine on localhost? How to fix?

Tags: javascript, three.js, github-pages, vite

I finished my first three.js project, and it runs fine and works on my local device (it's just a page of a black background and a ball that changed colour when you spin it).

However, when I uploaded it to GitHub to try and host it on GitHub pages it didn't render the Three.js animations and instead replaced the whole scene with a white background.

I tried changing the source of the stylesheets and scripts, varying from "/styles.css" to "./styles" to even "url.com/repo/myproject/styles.css" but nothing seemed to work.

If you'd like to look at my code, here is the [public repositiory](https://github.com/ryamon/eamons-planet), [github pages page](https://ryamon.github.io/eamons-planet/).

Comment: Try disabling Jekyll by dropping an empty `.nojekyll` file into the top-level directory.

Comment: I tried that, no change :(

Comment: Check the browser console for an error, it tells you there, ie "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "three". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: I looked and it does say that, but how would I fix that?

Comment: At line 2 of your `main.js`, you have `import './style.css';`  This, and the `package.json`, suggest to me that you're previewing locally using `$ vite`, but you're not doing a `$vite build` before you `$ push remote`.  I'm hardly a vite expert, though, so maybe someone with more vite experience can add their thoughts.

Comment: How would I do that?